# How to trigger logout from my google vue component

Tags: vue.js, google-auth-library

If user is login with google implement in vue component, how is it possible to trigger logout in the same component from the outside

Comment: it is possible - but when needed something went wrong ;)

Comment: @Estradiaz please can you show sample or elaborate?

Comment: no - but you are welcome to show where your issue is in your code and i can try to give you some pointers